# taggingJS throws an error while typing . AKA fullstop

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagging

I'm using this for tags: https://github.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS/

Below code is used to initialise the taaggingJS

```
var myOptions =
        {
            "no-duplicate": true,
            "no-duplicate-callback": null,
            "type-zone-class": "type-zone",
            "tag-box-class": "tagging",
            "forbidden-chars": ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+", "`", "~", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", ";", ":", "'", "<", ">", ",", ".", "/", "?"],
            "forbidden-chars-callback": null
            // chars not included ", 
        };

$("#post_tags").tagging(myOptions);
```

Whenever i am typing **. (fullstop)** in the div, it responds with an error stating

> Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function
>       at n.throwError (tagging.min.js:1)

Not able to figure out why? Could anyone help with this issue?

Comment: remove the line ""forbidden-chars-callback": null" and error will be gone. Also one more thing https://github.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS/#getting-started they have shared   a codepen link, in which you type "." then it's giving as "Forbidden Character" only. So I guess there is no need to add "." in "forbidden-chars" parameter values.

Comment: i don't want the alert to be shown, how to disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**forbidden-chars-callback** is the config parameter which decides what to do whenever a forbidden character found. Default value for that parameter is "window.alert", that's why the alert is coming while inputting a forbidden character.

**forbidden-chars-callback** expects a function wherein you had passed "null" to it, that's why an error is getting thrown.

Now, as per your request that alert need not to be shown & to do not show such errors. You can pass an anonymous function which does nothing to avoid javascript error.

Have a look at the JS Code

```
var myOptions = {
    "no-duplicate": true,
    "no-duplicate-callback": null,
    "type-zone-class": "type-zone",
    "tag-box-class": "tagging",
    "forbidden-chars": ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+", "`", "~", "[", "]", "{", "}", "|", ";", ":", "'", "<", ">", ",", ".", "/", "?"],
    "forbidden-chars-callback": function(){}
};

$("#post_tags").tagging(myOptions);
```

Full list of available specifications:
https://github.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS/#available-options

To have a look at the complete JS File, visit url:
https://cdn.rawgit.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS/master/tagging.js

[image]

Comment: Worked like charm :)